# RxJS finalize operator with shareReplay called for each subscriber

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code:

```
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(3),
  finalize(() => console.log('complete')),
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true}),
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Now, the complete log called once. When I move the `finalize` operator to be after the `shareReplay`, it called three times, which I guess it's per subscriber, but why it works like that?

```
   const source = interval(1000).pipe(
      take(3),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true}),
      finalize(() => console.log('complete')),
    );
```

The `finalize` operator subscribed to the internal `ReplaySubject` which complete once, no?

Comment: You already answered your question correctly. `shareReplay ` makes just one subscription to its source so `finalize` is called just once. If you use `finalize` after `shareReplay` then there're are three separate subscription to the Subject inside `shareReplay`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finalize** operator emits when its source observable is complete.

**ShareReplay** operator creates a **new** observable for each subscriber, and replay original observable values.

**Take** operator only completes after finishing to emit the specified number of take times.

So in your first case, **Take(3)** observable will emit 3 times, then it’s observable is complete and finalized is called once.

In your second case, **ReplayShare** will create a **new** observable per subscriber (over all 3 subscriptions) and finalized will be called 3 times, once for each created observable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand your explanation.

Comment: Mm I'm on my phone, later I will draw a diagram

Comment: @undefined I have edited my answer, hope it’s defined better

Comment: In other words, put the shareReplay after the finalize